# Android : ViewPager doesn't display the first 2 pages after being created again

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm using a ViewPager to display a list of bitmaps in each pages. When my activity is created, the ViewPager displays correctly.

When I click on a button, I want the ViewPager to display a different list of bitmaps, so I create and entirely new ViewPager by realocating the previous one. That's where the issue takes place : the first 2 pages of my new ViewPager aren't showing.

If I understand correctly, by default, a ViewPager preloads 2 pages. So if I'm looking at the first page, that means the second has been already created, and when I move to the second page, the third one is automatically created, etc.

When pages are being created dynamically according to the way I described above, the first and second pages that used to not be displayed are visible. But for that, I need to slide to the 4th page and come back to the first one, in order to create the first 2 pages and see them.

I looked for a way to force the first 2 pages to redraw, but with no result. If you have any question, don't hesitate to ask !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what u have tried? can you show some codes?

Answer (score 1):

just had the *exact* same issue. 
i was using the same `id` for the old and the new `ViewPager`. incredibly using two different ids fixed it.

Comment: having same issue...could you please elabore more??

Comment: it's a while ago, but i think i had the ID encoded in the xml file. somehow removing the old thingie and adding the new thingie confused the parent view. assigning a new (unique) ID to the new thingie solved the problem.